# <img> height CSS resizing incorrectly with percentages in a carousel

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have an `<img>` inside a `<div>`.

**My problem/what I have tried**

When I put `width: 100%;`, the `<img>` takes 100% of the width AND height, instead of just the width. When I put `height: 100%;`, it also doesn't work.

I tried `body,html{ width:100%, height:100;}` but that didn't produce the desired result either.

**What I need**

The slide needs to resize depending on the screen resolution, but the image inside of each slide should stay the same size for all screen resolutions.

**HTML**

```
    <div id="adcast-wrap" class="content">
        <div class="overflow">
            <ul id="adcast">
                <li class="adcast-item is-active"><img src="images/adcast-1.jpg" alt="" /></li>
                <li class="adcast-item"><img src="images/adcast-2.jpg" alt="" /></li>
                <li class="adcast-item"><img src="images/adcast-3.jpg" alt="" /></li>
                <li class="adcast-item"><img src="images/adcast-4.jpg" alt="" /></li>
                <li class="adcast-item"><img src="images/adcast-5.jpg" alt="" /></li>
            </ul><!-- #adacst -->
            <div id="pager">
                <img src="images/bullet-1.png" alt="" class="pager-item fleft is-active" data-adcast="0" />
                <img src="images/bullet-2.png" alt="" class="pager-item fleft" data-adcast="1" />
                <img src="images/bullet-3.png" alt="" class="pager-item fleft" data-adcast="2" />
                <img src="images/bullet-4.png" alt="" class="pager-item fleft" data-adcast="3" />
                <img src="images/bullet-5.png" alt="" class="pager-item fleft" data-adcast="4" />
            </div><!-- #pager -->
        </div><!-- .overflow -->
    </div><!-- #adacst-wrap -->

<script src="slideshow.js"></script>
<script>
(function() {
    "use strict";
    /*global document:false */
    var $ = function(selector) {
        return document.querySelectorAll(selector);
    },
        $adcasts = $('.adcast-item'),
        $pagers = $('.pager-item');

    adcast.init({
        adcasts: $adcasts,
        pagers: $pagers,
        pagersClick: true
    });

}());
</script>
```

**CSS**

```
*
{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
    border: none;
}
body, html
{
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background: #fff;
}
a
{
    text-decoration: none;
}
a:hover
{
    text-decoration: underline;
}
.content
{
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.fleft
{
    float: left;
}
.fright
{
    float: right;
}
.clear
{
    clear: both;
}
.overflow
{
    overflow: hidden;
}
.hidden-text
{
    overflow: hidden;
    text-indent: 100%;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
.is-hidden
{
    display: none;
}
img
{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%; /* <-------- Here is the issue */
}
#adcast-wrap
{
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 40%;
    padding: 1%;
    margin-top: 5%;
    background: #000;
    margin-bottom: 1%;
    position: relative;
}
#adcast-wrap .overflow
{
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
}
.adcast-item
{
    margin: 0 1% 1% 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    transition: 2s;
    opacity: 0;
}
#adcast .is-active
{
    opacity: 1;
}
#pager
{
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
    padding: 1%;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 10;
    right: 0%;
    bottom: 0%;
}
.pager-item
{
    cursor: pointer;
    border: 2px solid transparent;
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    border-radius: 50%;
}
.pager-item:hover, .pager-item.is-active
{
    border: 2px solid #FF0207;
}
```

Comment: can you [post your code here](http://jsfiddle.net/)

Comment: Does the parent have a height set to 100%. Too tired to look at the code.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a example: http://jsfiddle.net/fk7wuofr/1/

Do 1, 2 and next 3:

1. Remove the margin and put the li item 100%:

   ```
   .adcast-item {
    /* margin: 0 1% 1% 0; */
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    transition: 2s;
    opacity: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
   }
   ```
2. Remove the extra width:

   ```
   #adcast-wrap {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 98%;  /* <------ -2% */
    height: 40%;
    padding: 1%;
    margin-top: 5%;
    background: #000;
    margin-bottom: 1%;
    position: relative;
   }
   ```

or if you want it full screen:

```
    #adcast-wrap {
     display: inline-block;
     width: 98%;
     height: 98%; /* <--- This not works flawless for me in Chrome */
     /* it put me the scrollbars (but a little) */
     padding: 1%;
     background: #000;
     position: relative;
    }
```

3. Change the image selector:

   ```
   .adcast-item img {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
   }
   ```

Comment: Steps 2 and 3 can be optional, but i think you need it.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using  `height:100%;`  try  `height:100vh;` where `'vh'` is `'viewport height'`

Answer (score 0):

In your css code, use this-

```
body, html {
    height: 100%;
    width:100%; 
    background: #fff; 
    overflow-x:auto;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the size of your images, you'll need to use
    #adcast img{width:100%; height:auto}

or

```
#adcast img{width:auto; height:100%}
```

but you can also use this to force a full fill of the element and proper scaling (your containing element has no styling whatsoever, so no idea what do you plan to do with it)

```
#adcast img{width:auto; min-width:100%; height:auto}
```

This way, your image will be 100% f the containing element. Now you can give #adcast any width you want (even 100% or 100vw) and the image will resize accordingly